# Low validation accuracy while retraining inception v3

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm using a cat and dog dataset with 25000 images.

```python
xtrain.shape = (25000, 224, 224, 3)
ytrain.shape = (25000, 2)
```

Then using InceptionV3, I'm trying to fine tune the model on this dataset.

```python
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
base_model = InceptionV3(include_top=False,weights='imagenet')
base = base_model.output
layer1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base)
layer2 = Dense(128,activation='relu')(layer1)
prediction = Dense(2,activation='softmax')(layer2)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=prediction)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then I trained the last layer :

```python
model.fit(x=xtrain,y=ytrain,batch_size=100,
      epochs=10,verbose=1,validation_split=0.2)
```

Then I fine tuned the last 50 layers :

```python
for layer in model.layers[:250]:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[250:]:
    layer.trainable = True

from keras.optimizers import Adam
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), 
             loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=x,y=y,batch_size=100,epochs=50,verbose=1,validation_data= . 
         (xx,yy))
```

I'm training for 50 epoch, I'm getting around 95% training accuracy, but only 50% validation accuracy.
I don't understand why. Also the imagenet dataset already contains cat and dog class, so theere shouldn't be need of heavy training on my dataset. I know I'm wrong somewhere, someone please point out the error.

Comment: Start with only 1 Dense layer so you are less prone to overfitting. How is your validation accuracy if you only train the last layer?

Comment: then also validation accuracy is around 50%

Comment: This sounds really weird. You should get a good accuracy training only the last layer but I can't see any problem in your script. Check again the way you build the dataset and be sure you split it in the correct way. Also try other pretrained networks (like VGG16) to see if it changes something.

Comment: What accuracy did you get before the final finetuning? It would be cool if you could append plots of training accuracy vs validation accuracy across epochs to check if you are overfitting at the end to your training dataset, but even 95% seems low for such a simple dataset.

Comment: Yea i used VGG16 and rerun the code, now i'm gettting around 90% validation accuracy, but I still don't understand what was wrong with inception model. Anyway I'll again try with inception model now and see If I'm able to replicate the results